# Jquery AJAX to retrieve PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php script that makes my page load slowly because it fetches API data from another site and parses it so I want to make it load last.  I'm reading AJAX is the way to go because it is asynchronous.  Below is my AJAX code so far.  All I want to do at the moment is have AJAX fetch a variable from PHP and display it but I can't get it to work.  I think I'm really close though.

Here is the DIV I want it to load to and the script trigger.

```
<div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_lastcount();</script>
```

Here is the AJAX script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_lastcount() {
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("GET", "/viewcount.php", true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
       var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
       var results = document.getElementById("results");
       results.innerHTML = data;

       }
       }
     }
     hr.send(null);
     results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
```

Here is viewcount.php page

```
header("Content-type", "application/json");
$lastcount = "ten";
echo json_encode($lastcount);
```

Comment: Well, I do not see the jQuery AJAX request, only the pure JavaScript `XMLHttRequest` call. Do you want us to transform this into a jQuery AJAX request?

Comment: You have the jquery tag so why not use jQuery's ajax functions, it simplifies the problem, [jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  Your ajax request would then be `$.ajax({
url: "/viewcount.php"
}).done(function(data) {
$('#results').html(data);
});`  You may have to go through data if it is json, but a break point on it will let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery this could be achieved by this code (called automatically after the page's DOM is loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/viewcount.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        $('div#results').html(data);
    });
});
```

If you want to perform simplified `GET` or `POST` request, you can also call this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/viewcount.php', {'optional_params_object':'value'})
    .success(function(data) {
        $('div#results').html(data);
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('/viewcount.php', {'optional_params_object':'value'})
    .success(function(data) {
        $('div#results').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the simplified GET request and it worked just fine and shaved off time.  I was over complicating things.

Comment: Yes, you was, little bit. Pure `XmlHttpRequest` was used 8 years ago when the jQuery was still only in it's diapers. Since the AJAX requests were implemented into jQuery there is no reason to use `XmlHttpRequest` anymore :-). Glad it helped.